# Dynamically set display to None/Block of Table Row with group of Input Fields Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I hope someone can direct me to fixed this problem. Im using bootstrap 3, I need to dynamically set the display attritube of table row that has input groups. On page load the rest of my table rows are set to display:none using this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var current_range_count = $('#range_count').val();

    for (i = current_range_count; i <= 10; i++) {
        $("#advance_cost_range_" + i).css("display", "none");
    }

});
```

But when i set the display to block, when it shows up using the code line below on onchange event on one of the field on the second table rows, the appearance of it is a mess.

```
//Show next Cost Range
$("#advance_cost_range_3").css("display", "block");
```

See screenshot:

[image]

This is the code of the table row. It actually 10 copies of this. The first 2 table rows is displayed and the rest are set to display:none

```
      <tr id="advance_cost_range_1">
        <td style=" width: 22.5%; ">
        <div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="advance_price_min_1" type="number" min="0.00" value="0" step="1" class="form-control" ><span class="input-group-addon" >PHP</span>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" style=" width: 5%; ">
                    -
        </td>
        <td style=" width: 22.5%; ">
        <div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="advance_price_max_1" type="number" min="0.00" value="1000" step="1" class="form-control" ><span class="input-group-addon" >PHP</span>
            </div>
        </div>  
        </td>
        <td class="text-center" style=" width: 5%; ">
                <i id="advance_price_operator_1" class="fa fa-border fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>               
        <td style=" width: 22.5%;" >
            <div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="advance_price_rule_val_1" type="number" min="0.00" value="2" step="1" class="form-control" style=" width: 45%;">
                <select class="input-group-addon" id="advance_price_rule_op_1" style=" width: 55%;">
                  <option value="multiplier">Multiplier</option>
                  <option value="fixed">Fixed Markup</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>

        </td>
        <td style=" width: 22.5%;visibility: hidden; " class="advance_price_compare_1">

            <div class="form-group " style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input id="advance_price_rule_compare_val_1" type="number" min="0.00" step="1" class="form-control" style=" width: 45%;">
                <select class="input-group-addon" id="advance_price_rule_compare_op_1" style=" width: 55%;">
                  <option value="multiplier">Multiplier</option>
                  <option value="fixed">Fixed Markup</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>              

        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: Set the display to `table-row`.

Comment: Thank you so much!